# algorithm to randomly & efficiently place 100 circles without any overlap?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, heuristics

I am trying to write a script to place 100 circles of varying sizes onto a stage. I've outlined the concise requirements below.

**Given the following:**

```
var stage;       // contains a "width" and "height" property.
var circle;      // the circle class. contains x, y, radius & a unique id property.
var circleArray; // contains 100 circle instances
```

**requirements:**

- write a function to place 100 circles of varying radius onto the stage.
- placements must be random but evenly distributed (no clumping).
- placement must be performant - this will be executing on a mobile web browser.
- circles must not intersect/overlap other circles.
- `circle.x >= 0` must be true.
- `circle.y >= 0 && circle.y <= stage.height` must be true.
- circles may have any of the following radius sizes (assigned at creation):

  - 150
  - 120
  - 90
  - 80
  - 65

---

**My current attempt is a brute-force method, which does not operate efficiently. If I attempt to insert any more than ~10 circles, the browser hangs. Below is my current implementation, which I am completely OK with throwing away in favor of a more performant / better one.**

**Here is a live demo (NOTE: there is no actual drawing code, just the logic, but it will still lock up the browser so be warned!!) http://jsbin.com/muhiziduxu/2/edit?js,console**

```
function adjustForOverlap (circleArray) {
  // a reference to the circle that is invoking this function.
  var _this = this;

  // remove this circle from the array we are iterating over.
  var arr = circleArray.filter(function (circle){
    return circle.id !== _this.id;
  });

  // while repeat == true, the circle may be overlapping something.
  var repeat = true;
  while(repeat) {
    var hasOverlap = false;
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      var other = arr[i];
      var dx = _self.x - other.x;
      var dy = _self.y - other.y;
      var rr = _self.radius + other.radius;
      if (dx * dx + dy * dy < rr * rr) {
        // if here, then an overlap was detected.
        hit = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    // if hit is false, the circle didn't overlap anything, so break.
    if (hit === false) {
      repeat = false;
      break;
    } else {
      // an overlap was detected, so randomize position.
      _self.x = Math.random() * (stage.width*2);
      _self.y = Math.random() * stage.height;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In fact, if the space is small and the radii can't be zero, there might be no solution. This would iterate forever.

Comment: @Oriol the vertical space is confined (ie 0 - 500), however as much horizontal space can be used as needed (stage.width * n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [lots of efficient collision detection algorithms](https://www.google.com/search?q=efficient%20collision%20detection). Many of them work by dividing up the space into cells and maintaining a separate data structure with efficient lookup of other objects in the cell. The basic steps are:

1. Identify a random spot for your new circle
2. Determine which cells it's in
3. Look in each of those cells for a collision
4. If there's a collision, goto 1.
5. Else, add the new circle to each of the cells it overlaps.

You can use a simple square grid (i.e. a 2-d array) for the cell data structure, or something else like a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). You can also in some cases get a bit of extra speed by trying a cheap-but-coarse collision check first (do the bounding boxes overlap), and if that returns true try the slightly more expensive and exact check.

**Update**

For quadtrees, check out [d3-quadtree](https://github.com/d3/d3-quadtree), which ought to give you a pretty good implementation, with examples.

For a (very quick, untested) 2-d array implementation:

```
function Grid(radius, width, height) {
    // I'm not sure offhand how to find the optimum grid size.
    // Let's use a radius as a starting point
    this.gridX = Math.ceil(width / radius);
    this.gridY = Math.ceil(height / radius);
    // Determine cell size
    this.cellWidth = width / this.gridX;
    this.cellHeight = height / this.gridY;
    // Create the grid structure
    this.grid = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < gridY; i++) {
        // grid row
        this.grid[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < gridX; j++) {
            // Grid cell, holds refs to all circles
            this.grid[i][j] = []; 
        }
    }
}

Grid.prototype = {
    // Return all cells the circle intersects. Each cell is an array
    getCells: function(circle) {
        var cells = [];
        var grid = this.grid;
        // For simplicity, just intersect the bounding boxes
        var gridX1Index = Math.floor(
            (circle.x - circle.radius) / this.cellWidth
        );
        var gridX2Index = Math.ceil(
            (circle.x + circle.radius) / this.cellWidth
        );
        var gridY1Index = Math.floor(
            (circle.y - circle.radius) / this.cellHeight
        );
        var gridY2Index = Math.ceil(
            (circle.y + circle.radius) / this.cellHeight
        );
        for (var i = gridY1Index; i < gridY2Index; i++) {
            for (var j = gridX1Index; j < gridX2Index; j++) {
                // Add cell to list
                cells.push(grid[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return cells;
    },
    add: function(circle) {
        this.getCells(circle).forEach(function(cell) {
            cell.push(circle);
        });
    },
    hasCollisions: function(circle) {
        return this.getCells(circle).some(function(cell) {
            return cell.some(function(other) {
                return this.collides(circle, other);
            }, this);
        }, this);
    },
    collides: function (circle, other) {
        if (circle === other) {
          return false;
        }
        var dx = circle.x - other.x;
        var dy = circle.y - other.y;
        var rr = circle.radius + other.radius;
        return (dx * dx + dy * dy < rr * rr);
    }
};

var g = new Grid(150, 1000, 800);
g.add({x: 100, y: 100, radius: 50});
g.hasCollisions({x: 100, y:80, radius: 100});
```

Here's a fully-functional example: http://jsbin.com/cojoxoxufu/1/edit?js,output

Note that this only shows 30 circles. It looks like the problem is often unsolvable with your current radii, width, and height. This is set up to look for up to 500 locations for each circle before giving up and accepting a collision.

Comment: quad trees seem a bit complex but I'm interested to see an implementation of the 2d array method you describe.

Comment: Added a sample implementation. Have fun :)

Comment: This is really cool!!! Although I seem to be stuck on a bug - after adding my circles, when I check `hasCollisions()` it throws an error inside `getCells()`, specifically the `[j]` in `cells.push(this.grid[i][j])` appears to be undefined for some iterations. trying to debug at the moment but if you have any insight I'm all ears :) Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Im not positive, but it seems like the cell width/cell height aren't getting calculated properly. ie I pass in a radius of 150, but get a cell width/height of  148/120. does that mean my stage is simply not big enough?

Comment: That's because this uses `Math.ceil` for the number of cells. Using `Math.floor` would give you bigger cells, which might be better (it would ensure that a circle would span fewer cells). But either way you won't get exact cell sizes unless your height and width are exactly divisible by the radius.

Comment: hm.. Even with switching the cell sizing to use `Math.floor()` I still get a `cannot read property "X" of undefined`. I tried to create a jsbin out of my code but I can't seem to adapt it over to there (using local build processes and such) but if you dont mind taking a look it'd be appreciated http://jsbin.com/jacosotuja/edit?js,console

Comment: here's a newer demo.. for some reason it's always saying false for collisions, but I dont think that's right. http://jsbin.com/tibejiqecu/edit?js,console

Comment: I didn't put in any logic to constrain the circle to the bounds of the screen, so you're getting errors when the circle overlaps the edge.

Comment: Also you need to define collides()

Comment: Collides is defined (see jsbin ) - initial x/y are being set via Math.random() * screenHeight or screenWidth

Comment: See my update for a working example. My original code expected a standalone collides() function, not a method.

Comment: This is SO WONDERFUL. Thank you SO much for the demo and the thorough Explanation and communication throughout all my questions. I truly appreciate it! This is beautiful and I will be adapting your method to my needs (with attribution). Thank you!